# What do tensors of second order map to?

Tags: tensor-products, tensors, smooth-manifolds

On page 15 of James G. Simmonds book "A brief on Tensor Analysis" (chapter 1 of the first published edition), a second order tensor is described as an operator that sends vectors into vectors.  On page 311 of John M. Lee's book "Introduction to Smooth Manifolds" (second edition), all tensors are described as multilinear functions whose range is in R.  Being new to the subject of tensors, I have to ask which is it, are second order tensors mapped to vectors or to real numbers?  Obviously, I'm missing something basic -- please explain the concepts involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are often different ways of viewing the same sort of tensor, and people will often not bother to make the distinction. Natural isomorphisms between the operations that proudce the various tensors spaces justify this identification. In fact some notations for working with tensors will not even make a choice as to which viewpoint is being taken.

Here is an example. Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{R}$. Let $V^*$ denote the dual space.

**Claim:** A linear map $f:V\rightarrow V^*\ \ $ is the "same" thing as a bilinear map $F:V\times V\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

An $f$ corresponds to an $F$ given by
$$
F(v,w)=f(v)(w)
$$
and an $F$ corresponds to an $f$ given by
$$
f(v):V\rightarrow\mathbb{R},\ \ \ \text{given by}\ \ f(v)(w)=F(v,w).
$$

There are many correspondences like this one, some harder to prove than others.